# DateTime format not working as expected

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, format

### **HOW I NEED IT BUT DOESN'T WORK:**

First template/page:

```
    $publishDeadline = new DateTime($publishDate);
    $publishDeadline->add($published_to_draft_delay);
    update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'publishDeadline', $publishDeadline);
```

Other template/page:

```
    $publishDeadline = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'publishDeadline', true );  
    $publishDeadline->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    echo $publishDeadline;
```

- Messes up page layout and it doesn't echo anything
- If I use var_dump($publishDeadline) instead of format in second code, I'll get **string(19) "2015-08-25 00:45:44"**
- How it's saved in database (in phpMyAdmin): **O:8:"DateTime":3:{s:4:"date";s:26:"2015-08-25 01:32:18.000000";s:13:"timezone_type";i:3;s:8:"timezone";s:14:"Europe/Helsinki";}**
- ***How I need it to be:*** It must be as DateTime in post_meta for being usable by my functions and I need formated output in front-end

### **HOW IT WORKS BUT THAT'S NOT WHAT I NEED:**

First template/page:

```
    $publishDeadline = new DateTime($publishDate);
    $publishDeadline->add($published_to_draft_delay);
    $publishDeadline->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'publishDeadline', $publishDeadline);
```

Other template/page:

```
    echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'publishDeadline', true );
```

- Note how format is before updating post_meta & it works for mysterious reasons this way

*Ask if there's something you need to know.*

Comment: You're calling the `format()` method without assigning the result to anything (it returns a string); then trying to echo the DateTime object

Comment: `$formattedPublishDeadline = $publishDeadline->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    echo $formattedPublishDeadline;`

Comment: @MarkBaker Unfortunately same results.         `$publishDeadline = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'publishDeadline', true );  
        $formattedDeadline = $publishDeadline->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        echo $formattedDeadline;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**$publishDeadline->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');** works just fine after **get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'publishDeadline', true );**

Problem was that 1 post's post_meta was in other format from experimenting and debugging and it caused messed up layout and other errors.

Answer (score 1):

`format` doesn't change the object, it just returns the date in the given format.

Try this:

`update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'publishDeadline', $publishDeadline->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));`

Comment: That's the thing, I want it as unformated in post_meta because I need it like that for few functions. But I need to output is as formated in another code.

Comment: ? it's a date object, you can format it however you like. Check the docs for the rules here http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php